# Regular expression to find source and target

Tags: python, regex

Need help to write generic regular expression for to find the source table from the below scenarios:

Sample 1:

```
INSERT INTO a.test
(
test1,
test2
)
select 
test1,
test2
from 
xyz.test
```

Output 1:

```
xyz.test
```

Sample 2:

```
*******************************************************                                                                                
    MACRO                                                                 
        abc.test
    PURPOSE                                   
         TO DELETE THE DATA FROM abc.test
    INPUT PARAMS                              
                   NONE                                                                      
    CALLED BY                                                                            
        THIS MACRO IS BEING CALLED FROM sql
*******************************************************/ 
    DELETE FROM sample.test
```

No output for this as sample.Test is target table not source.

I have tried below regex `\b(?!DELETE\s+FROM\s+)(?:FROM|JOIN)\s+(\w+./*[^\s]+)` it's working for 1st scenario but for 2nd scenario I was expecting no output however I am getting sample.test

Comment: What flavor/tool are you using?

Comment: Hello,using Python.

Comment: I personally think that it will be rather complicated to do that with a regular expression as you'll have to handle comments, sub queries and all sorts of cases. I would prefer looking for a [SQL parser](https://github.com/topics/sql-parser). Perhaps something like [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot).

Comment: Hi @Patrick-Regular expression is working fine for 1st scenario just need to ignore the 2nd scenario as its target table not source. so for 2nd scenario its not working

Comment: Since non-fixed width lookbehind is not a thing in Python, perhaps you can use something like [`\b(?:(?<!DELETE )FROM|JOIN)\s+(\w+\.[^\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ErRmPl/1) (if there are multiple spaces between `DELETE` and `FROM`, this regex won't be able to handle it).

Comment: How about
`sql1 = """INSERT INTO a.test
(
test1,
test2
)
select 
test1,
test2
from 
xyz.test"""

sql2 = """
    DELETE FROM sample.test"""

TO_IGNORE = {'DELETE'}


def get_src_table_name(sql: str) -> str:
    words = sql.split()
    if words[-2].upper() == 'FROM' and words[-3] not in TO_IGNORE:
        return words[-1]
    return None


print(get_src_table_name(sql1))
print(get_src_table_name(sql2))
`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions , looking out for regex as its requirement for project for eliminating it.

Comment: This is becoming a more and more common issue.  The fact is, not all parsing problems are regular expression problems.  There are a lot of good resources on writing parsers.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think that a regular expression is the safe way to go.
There are really too many things to handle, such as comments, unions, etc.

I had a play with the
[SQLGlot library](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot#metadata) with this code:

```py
##python3 -m pip install sqlglot

from sqlglot import parse_one, exp

queries = [
"""
INSERT INTO a.test
(
test1,
test2
)
select 
test1,
test2
from 
xyz.test
""",
"""
/*******************************************************                                                                                
    MACRO                                                                 
        abc.test
    PURPOSE                                   
         TO DELETE THE DATA FROM abc.test
    INPUT PARAMS                              
                   NONE                                                                      
    CALLED BY                                                                            
        THIS MACRO IS BEING CALLED FROM sql
*******************************************************/ 
    DELETE FROM sample.test
""",
"""
SELECT
  t1.firstname,
  t1.lastname,
  t2.email,
  t3.order
FROM abc.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN abc.table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN abc.table3 t3 ON t3.email = t2.email
""",
"""
SELECT id, name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM table2
"""
]

for query in queries:
    print(query)
    sourceTables = []
    for select in parse_one(query).find_all(exp.Select):
        for table in select.find_all(exp.Table):
            sourceTables.append(str(table))
    print("Source tables:")
    print(sourceTables)
    print("\n")
```

It outputs the following:

```
INSERT INTO a.test
(
test1,
test2
)
select 
test1,
test2
from 
xyz.test

Source tables:
['xyz.test']



/*******************************************************                                                        

    MACRO
        abc.test
    PURPOSE
         TO DELETE THE DATA FROM abc.test
    INPUT PARAMS
                   NONE
    CALLED BY
        THIS MACRO IS BEING CALLED FROM sql
*******************************************************/
    DELETE FROM sample.test

Source tables:
[]



SELECT
  t1.firstname,
  t1.lastname,
  t2.email,
  t3.order
FROM abc.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN abc.table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN abc.table3 t3 ON t3.email = t2.email

Source tables:
['abc.table1 AS t1', 'abc.table2 AS t2', 'abc.table3 AS t3']



SELECT id, name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM table2

Source tables:
['table1', 'table2']
```

Seems to do what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

The following will capture the values from both of the provided examples.

As a note, a requirement is that the *"delete"*, *"from"*, or *"join"* are the first non-white-space character sequences on the line.

```
(?is)^\s*(?:delete\s+)?(?:from|join)\s*.*?([^\s]+)
```

The *(?is)* will toggle-on the *ignore case*, and *single-line* modes.

Output

```
xyz.test
sample.test
```